# How to force CSS background-images to fit to their containing element when zoomed in?

Tags: css, zooming

I have an unordered list (displayed vertically) that uses background-images to show a graphic inside each list item.

It looks fine until the user zooms. Once the user zooms, a tiny gap appears at the bottom (inside) of some list items. The gap appears because the background-image has become shorter than the list item, but the are both set to the same height (44px).

See this example. I added a red background to each list item to make the gaps easier to identify. Try zooming in once with Google Chrome.

http://jsbin.com/okozaz/2/edit

**Is there a way to remove the gap?**

I can't use background-size: cover because the background-image is part of a sprite.

Comment: Zoom is implemented differently from browser to browser. Value rounding makes certain assumptions that will sometimes never work.

Answer (score 0):

Probably due to some value rounding error, Chrome renders the `<li>`s differently when zooming in, resulting in some being 45px high and some 44px. However, a workaround would be to not set height and line-height on the li but leave that to the anchor element.

[See jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/henrikandersson/XAUPu/)

Answer (score 0):

Reduce height from 44px to 43px.
It seams to me, this helps in your example